# Extracting 3-d forms for producing organic shaped model from various flat parts

Tags: mesh, workflow, bezier-curves

I am a carpenter. Looking for a way to build organic shapes and curves in 3-d rendering that we can then extract 3-d pieces to understand the geometry required to build the form from multiple pieces of wood. This is a way to save material and build a 1-2" inch thick form that can curve in any direction. Pictures show simple forms that we built made by gluing up a series of small pieces cut at compound mitre angles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to know the length, area, angle of each piece?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Very nice works and project, I like them. Could you better explain what kind of help you need? Any kind of shape can surely be modeled, then cutted in pieces and the pieces "observed". Where are you exactly stuck? Modeling? Cutting in pieces? Examining the pieces?...

Comment: My take would be thinking about it backwards: create the final 3d shape you want, and then using the knife tool, or knife project, or bevel tools, make the cuts to figure out the shape and angles for the cuts.

Comment: Stuck a little all around. We want to make totally organic shapes from series of smaller pieces and need to know how to "mesh" in 3-d and extract the most efficient shapes (so there are series of matching pieces that create a certain form, which will likely be compound cuts....like, in order to create this form we need 120 pieces of wood at this size, with these angles, etc. and 60 pieces like this,  and 20 pieces like this.....

Comment: How do you do this today?

Comment: Sounds like you should define shape first, then cut if with knife project later